# Get the Maximum Key in a SortList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sortedlist

How do you determine what the maximum key is in a SortedList?  I've tried using the SortList.Max method and I can't get that to work.

Here's sample code:

```
Dim MySortedList As New SortedList(Of Int16, String)

MySortedList.Add(1, "Item 1")
MySortedList.Add(2, "Item 2")
MySortedList.Add(3, "Item 3")
MySortedList.Add(4, "Item 4")

'I added this just to demonstrates the sorted list is working
Response.Write(MySortedList(4))

'Now... how to I get the max 'Key' from the sorted list?
'In this example I want it to return the number '4'.

Dim MyMaxKey = MySortedList.Max <---- This doesn't work. Added as an example.

Response.Write(MyMaxKey)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim MyMaxKey = MySortedList.Keys.Max()
```

Comment: Excellent. This works as well.  Quick question if you don't mind... How would you use it as just "MySortedList.Max"?  I couldn't find an example. I assume you can because it's listed as (what I'll call) a "direct"  method of the SortedList object.

Comment: `Max` is an extension method defined for the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface.   T in this case is a `KeyValuePair(Of Int16, String)`. it doesn't make any sense to invoke the `Max` method on a sequence of `KeyValuePair`(s). How would you calculate which `KeyValuePair` is larger?

Answer (score 5):

Since the SortedList sorts by the key, you can simply take the last item's key - that's the max key:

```
    Dim MyMaxKey = MySortedList.Last().Key
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/l1d3AF